# Adding new grouping to a report

Tags: civireport, reports, custom-reports

I'd like to add a new grouping option to an existing report.

Is it possible to group by the payment instrument in the Contribution Summary Report? The option Payment Instrument is not showing up on the Grouping tab.

Is there any tutorial or explanation to do this? Or am I on an absolutely wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it covers this, but worth knowing about https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport as that would be one way to get your 'improvement' added if you have the skills/funds

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in the User Interface, you would have to develop a little extension that customizes the Contribution Summary Report by adding the Payment Instrument as an additional grouping. You can find some guidelines here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/civireport/

Or log a request at Gitlab for an improvement to the core report. You can do that here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues